# Linking 2 static libraries with target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I am trying to link two static libraries using cmake but I don't get the result I expect when I look into the libraries using `ar -t`.

A small example where library A is linked to B:

File `a.c`:

```
void a(){}
```

File `b.c`:

```
void b(){}
```

File `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(test C)

add_library(a STATIC "a.c")
add_library(b STATIC "b.c")
target_link_libraries(a b)
```

I expected to see both object files in the output `ar -t liba.a` but instead I only see `a.c.o` in the output.

Comment: Have you checked CMake documentation before, to verify your expectations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link static library using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901128/link-static-library-using-cmake)

Comment: When a **static** library is created, linking stage isn't actually performed. This is not a specific of CMake, this just an origin of static libraries. In your case call to `target_link_libraries(a b)` affects only on usage of `a` library later in the project. E.g. if an executable will link to `a` library, it will be automatically linked to `b` library. But again, the file, corresponded to `a` library, doesn't contain information about `b` library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I can see now my question is not new and you are right, but do you have a link to the documentation about your assertion?

Comment: No, I don't have a link to documentation. But there is a lot of question on Stack Overflow about this. E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334257/how-do-i-statically-link-a-library-into-another-static-library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining several static libraries into one using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

You can always debug your CMakeLists.txt using the VERBOSE=ON argument to make (on Linux) this way you can verify if the commands are the one you expect.

```
$> make VERBOSE=ON
```

In your case CMake scan the dependencies of *a.c* and it discard *b.c* as real dependency for *a.c*, that's why it's not linked.