# How to merge two windows vc static library into one

Tags: c, visual-studio, merge, static-libraries, visual-c++

I am having a two static library `a.lib` and `b.lib`(of C language) which is generated using VC6 (Visual studio 6.0) .

I want to merge these two libs into one static lib `c.lib`. How to do this in CLI mode?

I have seen the [merging of *nix static libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one).
I want to do the samething with VC6 static libs in CLI mode.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**LIB.EXE /OUT:c.lib a.lib b.lib**

LIB.EXE is available in < VC6_InstalledFolder >/VC98/BIN. And this LIB.EXE is available in all versions of visual studio.