# Producing a hybrid static library with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, static-libraries

It is my understanding that Visual Studio library projects use two separate processes after compiling, depending on the "General/Configuration type" setting:

- If "static library" is selected, all of the object files are bundled together into the final `.lib` file, a *static library*.
- If "dynamic library" is selected, all of the object files are linked together, along with dependencies, and bundled into the final `.dll` file, a *dynamic library*. Meanwhile, all of the `__declspec(dllexport)` symbols are gathered, and used to generate a `.lib` file, the *import library*.

I would like to create a `foo.lib`/`foo.dll` pair, where `foo.lib` is both an import library for `foo.dll` *and* a static library on its own. I have considered the following leads:

- Create two separate projects, `FooLib` and `FooDll`, and [use `lib.exe` in a post-build step to merge both `.lib` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492365/how-to-merge-two-windows-vc-static-library-into-one). This sounds like the easiest option but requires splitting in half what should otherwise be a cohesive module.
- Create a single DLL project, let the default build process create `foo.dll` and its import library. Then add custom build steps to manually gather the object files and bundle them into the import library with lib. This sounds messy, and I'm not sure what the duplicates will do.
- I've tried messing around with `.def` files, but even after `dumpbin`ing the resulting lib files I'm a bit perplexed by its behaviour. Also, it needs an explicit list of mangled symbols, which is impractical.

Is there a simpler way to achieve that hybrid `.lib`/`.dll` combo? Otherwise, which lead should I rather follow?

---

**Background**

This module will be used in several `.dll`s and one `.exe` linked together. I need to have a single instance of half of its data in the resulting process at runtime (which is achieved by the `.dll`, since it will be only loaded once), while the other half is duplicated into each `.dll` or `exe` and initialized therein (which is achieved by the `.lib`).

Comment: I actually don't understand the background... Couldn't you just split your code, the part should be a static lib in one project, and the part for the dynamic lib in another? Plus data being unique at runtime can be achived with dll's!!!

Comment: @user1810087 you described lead #1 :) I'll try to clarify that last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally taken the first route I listed in the question: create two projects, a static library and a dynamic library, and merge their outputs. This ended up being easier than expected: I just had to register the DLL's import library as a dependency for the static library's "Librarian" build step, and setup a project reference to have the correct build order.

`FooDll.vcxproj`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- snip snip snip -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetName>Foo</TargetName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <Link>
            <ImportLibrary>$(OutDir)FooDll.lib</ImportLibrary>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <!-- snip snip -->
</Project>
```

`Foo.vcxproj`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- snip snip snip -->
    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <Lib>
            <AdditionalDependencies>$(OutDir)FooDll.lib;$(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Lib>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <!-- snip snip -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\FooDll\FooDll.vcxproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <!-- snip -->
</Project>
```

The end result is a `Foo.dll`/`Foo.lib` pair, the latter being both a static library on its own and an import library for `Foo.dll`.

I still have to straddle two projects, but this is simple enough that I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot create a single .lib for this, however you can use msvc's #pragma comment(lib, ) to achieve much the same thing, you simply have more than one #pragma comment(lib, ) one for the dynamic .lib and one for the static.

Comment: Hmm, `#pragma comment`... That could also be a nicer way of sticking the import lib and the static lib together without resorting to `lib.exe` if I put it inside the static lib.

Comment: @Quentin:  Why don't you make a lib, and make a dll from the lib?  They will obviously not be both referenced at the same time from projects that use them.  If that is not what you had in mind, you are engaging yourself into a design dead-end.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy because they should have one half each of the data, not the same contents.

Comment: And a dll's data belings to its calling process.  While several instances of a dll (in different processes) may share the same physical address for its code segment, that is not at all the case for its data.  Each process has its own data, even if it belongs to a dll.

Comment: Maybe what you really want is not a dll, but a global data provider, which is a service.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Oh, I see what you mean now. I'm in the scope of a single process, which contains the `.exe`, several `.dll`s and the hybrid thingy.