# Android : merging static libraries into single one

Tags: android, merge, android-ndk, static-libraries, unix-ar

I use Android NDK r8 to generate multiple static libraries with **include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)** and I successfully get : lib1.a, lib2.a, lib3.a, etc.

Now I would like to merge these static libraries into single one.

I try do it with ar.exe from Android NDK :

```
android-ndk-r8\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\arm-linux-androideabi\bin\ar.exe r libALL.a lib1.a lib2.a lib3.a
```

But when I use **libAll.a** into Android NDK makefile, it fails saying there is no index.

How can I add this index ?

**Other question :**

When I display contents of archive **libAll.a**, I see **lib1.a**, **lib2.a**, **lib3.a** instead of **.o** symbols from these libraries.

How can I change that (= extract .o from static libraries to merge it in libAll.a) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ar` is simply an archiving tool like zip. It takes the given input files and produces an `.a`archive. If you want to include all `.o`files in a single archive, you have to specify each individual file. I don't know how to do this on WIndows, but on Linux you can use somthing like `ar rs $(find . -name *.o)`.

Comment: OK, thanks for answer. Do you know which tool I have to use to merge .a in single one ?

Comment: You could try `ar x` to extract all object files and `ar rs` them again. However, I do not know whther this might screw some paths up. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one