# gcc/clang library compiling, include other library

Tags: c, gcc, clang

If you would create a library with c, that depends on another library, say `cURL`, you would compile it to a static library like this:

```
clang myLibrary.c -lcurl -c
ar myLibrary.a myLibrary.o
```

But, if you were to include this library in your application, you would get an error because some functions were not found (the cURL ones).

Is there a way to include libraries (in this case cURL) in the library at compile time?
I'm working on a linux machine

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one

Comment: So, you basically just merge the dependencies with your own library?

Comment: The true meaning of your "to include libraries" is actually merging those object files together into another object file, executable or a library. What else do you expect?