# Merge two static libraries into one - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, static-libraries

I have built two static libraries, lets call them `staLib1` & `staLib2`.

`staLib2` is dependent on `staLib1` for building.

Now, I want to know whether it is possible to write a build script in `staLib2` project to make both the libraries(.a files) into one library(.a).

I know there is:-

1. Creating a dependency project sample - Problem is it generates two `.a` files.
2. Using `libTool` script after the `.a` files are generated. - Not a build script.

Is there a build script that can do this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want them merged into one library? If you've got static libraries, they're going to be compiled into the final app binary anyways, so I assume this is just for convenience. Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one

Comment: @TristanSeifert : Yes, the reason being I do not want to give the end users two binaries. As for the link, it does not provide a build script. I need to merge that manually after building both the libraries.

Comment: Do you need your library consumer to be able to use directly `staLib1` at all or does `staLib2` provide / wrap all the functionality?

Comment: `staLib2` will encapsulate all the functionality. Thus in the headers of `staLib2` the headers of `staLib1` will also be added!!