# archive ffmpeg all objs into one lib, feasible?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, static-libraries, unix-ar

I've build ffmpeg static libraries, generated: libavformat.a, libavcodec.a, libavutil.a, ...

in their source directories, all necessary objs (*.o) generated.

I use 'ar' to archive all these objs into one libffmpeg.a.

command: **ar rc libffmpeg.a *.o.**

I notice that, there are some objs have same name in diff dirs, for example libavformat/4xm.o and libavcodec/4xm.o.

by 'nm libffmpeg.a', it seems both objs are there?

I'm NOT sure.

if obj with same name and Exactly with same function symbols, latter one will be replaced ,right?

by this 'ar' way, will libffmpeg.a work correctly? because there so many symbols I can't test every one.

thanks for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two "ar" static libraries into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one)

Comment: In that question I linked to, don't look at the accepted answer. Look at Guillem Jover's answer. I also added a comment that might be of some help.

Comment: Also, if you do `ar -t libffmpeg.a` it'll show you which files are in the archive, so you can verify that files with duplicate names are both in there.