# What's the difference between these two ar commands

Tags: unix, static-libraries, unix-ar

What's the difference between:

```
ar -x liba.a
ar -x libb.a
ar rcs libab.a *.o
```

and

```
ar rcs libab.a liba.a libb.a
```

Are they really doing the same task?

Comment: Do you mean the difference between just the two "ar rcs" lines? And if so, did you mean "*.a" and not "*.o"?

Comment: Yes this two command do the same thing. No? What's the difference between extract with -x and create a static library with all .o or create library directly with .a?

Comment: No, they don't do exactly the same thing. Try "ar rcs libab1.a *.o" and "ar rcs libab2.a liba.a libb.a" and then compare the contents of each (ar tv <file>.a).  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using a version of `ar` that I don't know about, the effects of the two sequences of commands are quite different — though both end up creating a file `libab.a`.

The first sequence extracts all the (object) files from `liba.a` into the current directory, then all the files from `libb.a` (any name collisions mean the file from `libb.a` will survive), and then all the object files that are now in the directory (possibly including ones that were in neither `liba.a` nor `libb.a`) are archived in `libab.a`.

The second sequence creates an archive that itself contains two files: `liba.a` and `libb.a`.  This is legal and feasible, but the resulting file isn't useful in linking programs.  The linker doesn't look at nested archives; it will simply find no object files that supply any symbols (since neither `liba.a` nor `libb.a` is an object file), so the library will effectively be unused — though you'll not get an error from attempting to use it.

It is more likely that the first sequence of commands is useful than the second.