# CMake building a static library with other static library

Tags: cmake, openssl, static-libraries

My problem is as follows :

I have **OpenSSL** as static libraries (`libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a`).
Compiled on Windows with **MSys2/MinGW64**.
Besides that, I have a small self written library based on `OpenSSL`.

Now I want to "bundle" the `Crypto lib` from `OpenSSL` with My lib to a "big" static library for later statically compiling in other applications on Windows without deploying any library.

What would a `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like? And are the prerequisites (`OpenSSL` as `static libs`) correct?

Actually compiling this to a dynamic `DLL` works like a charm. But My static lib are only includes the symbols of My own library, not from `OpenSSL` too.

Actually I have no working `CMake` file, so I can't include an example. I'm just looking for a direction how to do it.

A short suggestion how to begin would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In short, CMake [doesn't help](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-April/036669.html) you in combining several static libraries into single one. You may use `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target` for specify utilities invocation, which does that job. CMake-**unrelated** ways see in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you really want to do is combine multiple static libraries into one, for the convenience of external consumers, you'll probably need to run a custom command to do this (as it's not something that's frequently done).

Using the GNU toolchain, the commands to do so might look something like this (untested though):

```
${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory tempdir
cd tempdir
${CMAKE_AR} x $<yourlib:TARGET_FILE>
${CMAKE_AR} x ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}
${CMAKE_AR} x ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY}
${CMAKE_AR} cf ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/libyourmegalib.a *.o
cd ..
${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory tempdir
```

Then you would use `add_custom_command()` to create a target to run this script - either put those lines as `COMMAND` arguments, or create a script template, substitute values at CMake generation time using `configure_file()`, then have the custom command run that script.

That said, if the external consumers are all using CMake themselves, I would skip this entirely, and just have the installation process for your library generate CMake package configuration files that declare the dependencies on the OpenSSL libraries.

Comment: Thanks alot, now CMake becomes more clear. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

[target_link_library()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) works both for [add_executable()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html#command:add_executable) and [add_library()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html#command:add_library), so you should be able to do:

```
add_library(yourlib STATIC ...)
target_link_libraries(yourlib lib1 lib2 ...)
```

(where `yourlib` is your library, and `lib1`, ... are the libraries you want to bundle.

Comment: `target_link_libraries` doesn't **bundle** other libs into your one. So, when create an application which uses `yourlib`, it still requires `lib1`, `lib2` libraries to be existed.