# How to bundle multiple static libraries into single library in CMake for windows

Tags: windows, cmake, static-libraries

I want to bundle five static libraries into one library in CMake. How can I proceed for this?

Like library a, b, c, d, and e should bundle into `alpha_lib`.

Comment: The question about combining static libraries into a single one is frequently asked. Have you tried to search such questions? E.g. how your question differs from that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945142/cmake-building-a-static-library-with-other-static-library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can take advantage of the [Microsoft Library Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/lib-reference?view=vs-2019) (LIB.exe) to **combine** your static libraries into one. Your CMake could follow these steps:

1. Use [`find_program()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) to have CMake locate the MSVC `lib.exe` tool on your system. If you run `cmake` from the Visual Studio Command Prompt, `find_program` can locate `lib.exe` automatically,  without using the optional `PATHS` argument to tell it where to look.
2. Use CMake's [`add_custom_target()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) command to call `lib.exe` using the syntax for *merging* libraries:

   ```
   lib.exe /OUT:alpha_lib.lib  a.lib b.lib c.lib d.lib e.lib
   ```

   You can use target-dependent [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#target-dependent-queries) in the custom target command to have CMake resolve the locations of your built libraries. The custom target will create a Project in your Visual Studio solution that can be run separately to merge all of the built static libraries into one library.

Your CMake could look something like this:

```
# Create the static libraries (a, b, c, d, and e)
add_library(a STATIC ${a_SOURCES})
...
add_library(e STATIC ${e_SOURCES})

# Tell CMake to locate the lib.exe tool.
find_program(MSVC_LIB_TOOL lib.exe)

# If the tool was found, create the custom target.
if(MSVC_LIB_TOOL)
    add_custom_target(CombineStaticLibraries
        COMMAND ${MSVC_LIB_TOOL} /OUT:$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:a>/alpha_lib.lib
            $<TARGET_FILE:a> 
            $<TARGET_FILE:b> 
            $<TARGET_FILE:c> 
            $<TARGET_FILE:d> 
            $<TARGET_FILE:e> 
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    )
endif()
```