# msvc & cmake fully link static library with other static libraries (bundle)

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, static-libraries

I' am currently attempting to build my own small graphical library that also uses imgui internally and want to distribute this single static library (/MT for release and /MTd for dbg).

How would I fully link imgui to my lib so that when I link my library to an application so that I don't have to link imgui against the executable too.

So basically I would like to bundle my library (which relies on imgui) and imgui into a single lib.

Currently I am just using `target_link_libraries()` like so:

```
# Set targets
add_library(final_lib STATIC ........cpp)

# Add dependencies
find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(imgui CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(final_lib PUBLIC fmt::fmt imgui::imgui)
```

Is there a way to bundle `fmt, imgui` into `final_lib` ?

Regards Artur

Comment: If you have `fmt` and `imgui` as static libraries, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60190374/how-to-bundle-multiple-static-libraries-into-single-library-in-cmake-for-windows) about combining them and your library into the single static library. If you have `fmt` and `imgui` as shared libraries, then you cannot merge them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the answer worked perfectly