# How to make linking to a static library also link to its dependency as well?

Tags: c, build, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I wrote a static library called `libverify_passwd.a` using `llvm-ar-7`, which use symbol `getpwuid`, 
`getspnam` and `crypt`. It requires special linker argument `-lcrypt` and `-lc` (if `-nostdlib` is specified).

Another project of mine depend on this static library and it will be cumbersome and hard to maintain by adding `-lcrypt` to the `Makefile` of that project. Is there any way so that during the link time, the dependency can be solved automatically, or is there any other tool that simplify the maintenance of this?

Comment: You may benefit from using CMake to generate your make files. But generally, asking for tool recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Static libraries are not created by the linker. Since no linkage happens
in the creation of a static library, you cannot link anything to a static library.
Read [the Stackoverflow tag wiki about static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info)

Comment: Add the list of required libraries to the documentation of your library. You may add examples of the linker command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [How to merge two “ar” static libraries into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one) to make a new lib containing what you want

However the best way is to continue to use `-lcrypt` at link time