# How to create a static library which includes another static library

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, qt-creator

I have a C++ project called testlib.pro (using Qtcreator) which will create a static library libtest.a.

The project is also included staticlib.a (example) and staticlib1.a. i.e using someother static libraries im creating one static library. After creating static library, Im creating C wrapper (testApi.c) to use the C++ code using the static library. I am compiling the testApi.c using the below option

gcc -o demo testApi.c -L ./testlib -ltest

But it is giving linker errors which stats that it requires the static libraries which i used to link the libtest.a. So i recompile the program with below comment and it works fine

gcc -o demo testApi.c -L ./testlib -ltest -lstatuclib -lstaticlib1

My understanding is If I ship the libtest.a to someother machine and try to compile testApi.c file it may requires staticlib.a and staticlib1.a in that machine. But I would like to use only newly created static library libtest.a. Am i missing any?

NOTE: I have included staticlib.a, staticlib1.a using -l option in my testlib.pro

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one

Comment: Remember that static libraries are nothing more than archives of object files. So it's possible to extract the object files from the "other" static library, and add them to your own. Not that I really recommend it though.

Answer (score 7):

If your library uses other static libraries then they will also need to be provided at link time.

There is an ugly way around it (on Linux). You can unpack existing static library (or several of them) and repack them into a new library. So you could, if you felt particularly frisky, unpack those libraries that yours depends on, then pack their contents along with your own stuff into a new library. Ugly, confusing, possibly causing all sorts of other problems, but if that is the way you want to go...

Comment: That ugly way happens to be exactly what libtool does, so if one learns how to use libtool and build static libraries with libtool, libtool will do all that nastiness for you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Are you sure that libtool does that? Then what's the `dependency_libs` entry of the libtool *.la files for?

Comment: They are what libtool, the script, uses to do all of this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think that's true, from what I can see libtool reads these *.la files in the linker stage, and adds these dependencies to the linker command. The static libraries itself are not modified.

Comment: @ssbssa - feel free to bootstrap the following Makefile.am: https://pastebin.com/1ti5eUEz - repeat this experiment, and then explain how `world.o` winds up in `libhello.a` without libtool doing what I said it does.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Nice, I didn't know libtool could do that.

Answer (score 1):

The static library concept is archaic in nature.  When a program had a lot of modules, it was sometimes impossible to put them  all in the command line for the linker to add them to the program.  Also, for libraries, as the `.o` modules where all being included in the final executable, there had to be some mechanism to allow the linker select only the needed modules and not to include all of them in the final executable, or the executables will grow a lot including modules that the program will not use.  Both things where solved with the introduction of dynamic shared objects, so using `.a` files is somewhat deprecated today and it is only used for statically linking programs.

Anyway, the algorithm to select the object modules in the linker is not recursive, so when it opens a `.a` library to search for dependent files to be included in the final executable, it searches only for `.o` (and probably `.so`, but I have not tested this), and it will ignore any `.a` file it finds in there.  Many systems include an index file in the archive that has a mapping between provided identifiers, and the name of the module that provides them, so in one pass the compiler knows which archived objects need to be extracted.  That index file should be appended (and rebuilt) in case a library (with its own index) where included in the file, so this justifies not using recursion at all in the library search.

The solution for this problem, is to link all those libraries you need to make the final executable, or as you have already been told, to extract the `.o` files in the library and put them in another library.  There is still a third solution, that is: The linker allows you to specify a file that has options (and you can specify library names, and `.o` files you want it to scan) and it will read that file to check the set of libraries you want it to scan.

Another point is that the linker never includes a library as such.  A library is just an archive (like a `.tar` or `.zip` file) in which the linker explores and *extracts* the files it needs, so there's no need to make the search algorithm recursive at all.  And there's no difference between an archived file in a library and that same file out of the archive.