# How to include static libraries in a static library?

Tags: cmake

I have 2 static libraries in two different folders: `libA` and `libB`

- `libB` must include `libA`

My main CMakeLists.txt is:

```
add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)
```

My first mistake was to think linking libA in libB would include it but it isn't:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC libA::libA)
```

I get `undefined reference to some libA's functions` when I try to use libB in an app.

- How can I tell CMake to include libA as part of libB?
- What's the best practice for that?

  - I'd like to avoid any extra step ([How to merge two "ar" static libraries into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one))

Answer (score 0):

If you control the builds for both `libA` and `libB`, you can solve this by creating `OBJECT` libraries `libA-obj` and `libB-obj`. You would then link `libA-obj` to `libA` and then link *both* object libraries to `libB`.

---

Here's a more detailed sketch

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(example)

# ...

# Can be in subdirectory
add_library(libA-obj ${libA-srcs})
add_library(libA)
target_link_libraries(libA PUBLIC libA-obj)

# Can be in subdirectory
add_library(libB-obj ${libB-srcs})
add_library(libB)
target_link_libraries(libB PUBLIC libB-obj libA-obj)

# Can be in parent directory
add_executable(app ${app-srcs})
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE libB)
```

Comment: Thanks but how? I'm completely lost with all the examples that do only partially what I want. I have `add_library(objlib OBJECT ${SRC})` in each CMakeLists.txt but how about the top one?

Comment: @Alexis - I've updated my answer to include a more detailed sketch

Comment: What if I don't need static library for libA? Also, what if there is a third libC that is nested? libA->libB-libC? I don't want to reference libA in libC since it's already in libB.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the object files that comprise `libA` to the sources of `libB` to include them:

```
target_sources(LibB PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:LibA>)
```

Comment: Here this doesn't seem to work, cmake 3.27.8 on Linux, LibA is an OBJECT library, LibB is a STATIC libary and the resulting LibB.a does not contain the .o's of LibA