# TensorFlow static C API library - how to link with 10 sub-dependencies?

Tags: c, tensorflow, cmake, tensorflow-lite, meson-build

I am trying to link with static C API version of the TensorFlow library.
I built the static library using the following commands:

```
// get the sources
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow_src

// create a build directory
mkdir builddir
cd builddir

// build the lib using CMake
cmake -S ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/c -DTFLITE_C_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
cmake --build . -j
```

This builds the `libtensorflow-lite.a`. However, the `libtensorflow-lite.a` is not self-contained and has its own set of 10 dependencies, stated [here in the CMake file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e41d9eb9edcc1ff2cf52736edde76e6f5d62f6ed/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt#L139):

```
# TensorFlow Lite dependencies.

find_package(absl REQUIRED)
find_package(eigen REQUIRED)
find_package(farmhash REQUIRED)
find_package(fft2d REQUIRED)
find_package(flatbuffers REQUIRED)
find_package(gemmlowp REQUIRED)
find_package(neon2sse REQUIRED)
find_package(clog REQUIRED)
find_package(cpuinfo REQUIRED)  #CPUINFO is used by XNNPACK and RUY library
find_package(ruy REQUIRED)
```

The question is, how do I find out the `.a` names of the required sub-libraries?

I used `find ./builddir -type f -name "*.a"` to list the libraries built by CMake, and expected roughly 10 libs, but the actual list is too long:

```
./_deps/xnnpack-build/libXNNPACK.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx2_fma.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_block_map.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_system_aligned_alloc.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx512.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/profiler/libruy_profiler_instrumentation.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_trmul.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_cpuinfo.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_blocking_counter.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_arm.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_apply_multiplier.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx2_fma.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_prepacked_cache.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_tune.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_context_get_ctx.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_ctx.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_wait.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_allocator.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_context.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_prepare_packed_matrices.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx512.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_arm.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_denormal.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx512.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_frontend.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx.a
./_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_thread_pool.a
./_deps/flatbuffers-build/libflatbuffers.a
./_deps/fft2d-build/libfft2d_fftsg2d.a
./_deps/fft2d-build/libfft2d_fftsg.a
./_deps/farmhash-build/libfarmhash.a
./_deps/clog-build/libclog.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/synchronization/libabsl_graphcycles_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/synchronization/libabsl_synchronization.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_strings.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_str_format_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_cord.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_strings_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/status/libabsl_status.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/hash/libabsl_city.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/hash/libabsl_wyhash.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/hash/libabsl_hash.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_reflection.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_program_name.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_private_handle_accessor.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_marshalling.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_commandlineflag_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_commandlineflag.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_config.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/numeric/libabsl_int128.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging/libabsl_symbolize.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging/libabsl_debugging_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging/libabsl_demangle_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging/libabsl_stacktrace.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_spinlock_wait.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_raw_logging_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_malloc_internal.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_throw_delegate.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_exponential_biased.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_base.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_log_severity.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/time/libabsl_time_zone.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/time/libabsl_civil_time.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/time/libabsl_time.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/container/libabsl_hashtablez_sampler.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/container/libabsl_raw_hash_set.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/types/libabsl_bad_variant_access.a
./_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/types/libabsl_bad_optional_access.a
./_deps/cpuinfo-build/libcpuinfo.a
```

The state of the libs seems to be the following:

1. absl: 30 libraries found
2. eigen: OK, template library defined in the headers
3. farmhash: OK, 1 library found
4. fft2d: OK, 2 libraries found
5. flatbuffers: OK, 1 library found
6. gemmlowp: OK, headers only
7. neon2sse: OK, headers only
8. clog: OK, 1 library found
9. cpuinfo: OK, 1 library found
10. ruy: 30 libraries found

All in all, most libs are OK, either there is 1 lib to link with, or the libs are header-only. What remains to be the problem are:

- absl
- ruy

because they contain about 30 `.a` libs.
Not sure if I have to link with all of those? It would be very cumbersome, as my build system is Meson and I am using [custom_target()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#custom_target) to link with TensorFlow.

Answer (score 2):

A year later, but I just went through this myself, so here goes my answer.
Based on my experience (using a makefile and without your `-DTFLITE_C_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF`) a program that performs inference does not need to link to Abseil.
You need to link to all other libs you mentioned, except `ruy_kernel_arm` and `ruy_pack_arm`, assuming you're running your program on the x64 platform. (Annoyingly `-DTFLITE_ENABLE_RUY=OFF` is not respected when building TfLite, so you're stuck with Ruy)

##### Detailed steps:

Build TfLite:

```
mkdir ~/my_tflite_project
cd ~/my_tflite_project/
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow_src
mkdir tflite_build_x64
cd tflite_build_x64/
cmake ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/
    /* You may encounter two CMake messages:
    -- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
    I believe a Fortran compiler is only necessary to build Fortran bindings for TfLite.

    -- Could NOT find CLANG_FORMAT: Found unsuitable version "0.0", but required is exact version "9" (found CLANG_FORMAT_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND)
    sudo apt install clang-format-9
    Annoyingly you need clang-format-9, plain clang-format (version 13, the newest) won't do. */
cmake --build . -j 4
```

Relevant libs:

```
$ cd ~/my_tflite_project/tflite_build_x64
$ ls *.a
libtensorflow-lite.a
$ ls pthreadpool/*.a
pthreadpool/libpthreadpool.a
$ ls _deps/*/*.a
_deps/clog-build/libclog.a        _deps/farmhash-build/libfarmhash.a  _deps/fft2d-build/libfft2d_fftsg2d.a      _deps/xnnpack-build/libXNNPACK.a
_deps/cpuinfo-build/libcpuinfo.a  _deps/fft2d-build/libfft2d_fftsg.a  _deps/flatbuffers-build/libflatbuffers.a
$ ls _deps/ruy-build/ruy/*.a
_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_allocator.a         _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_ctx.a                           _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx.a       _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_prepacked_cache.a
_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_apply_multiplier.a  _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_denormal.a                      _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx2_fma.a  _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_prepare_packed_matrices.a
_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_block_map.a         _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_frontend.a                      _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx512.a    _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_system_aligned_alloc.a
_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_blocking_counter.a  _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx.a       _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_arm.a         _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_thread_pool.a
_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_context.a           _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.a  _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx.a         _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_trmul.a
_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_context_get_ctx.a   _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx512.a    _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx2_fma.a    _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_tune.a
_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_cpuinfo.a           _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_arm.a                    _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx512.a      _deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_wait.a
```

Construct MWE using TfLite:

```
$ cd ~/my_tflite_project
$ mkdir my_dev_x64
$ cd my_dev_x64/
/* Construct minimal.cpp and makefile below */
$ cat minimal.cpp
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile("your_network_here.tflite");
    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;

    std::cout "Done\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

$ cat makefile
COMPILER     := g++

LINKER       := g++

CXX_FILES    := minimal.cpp

OBJ_FILES    := $(CXX_FILES:.cpp=.o)

EXE_FILE     := app

INCLUDE_DIRS := -I../tensorflow_src -I../tflite_build_x64/flatbuffers/include

LIB_DIRS     := \
        -L../tflite_build_x64 \
        -L../tflite_build_x64/_deps/fft2d-build \
        -L../tflite_build_x64/_deps/flatbuffers-build \
        -L../tflite_build_x64/_deps/ruy-build/ruy \
        -L../tflite_build_x64/_deps/farmhash-build \
        -L../tflite_build_x64/_deps/xnnpack-build \
        -L../tflite_build_x64/_deps/cpuinfo-build \
        -L../tflite_build_x64/_deps/clog-build \
        -L../tflite_build_x64/pthreadpool

LIBS         := \
        -ltensorflow-lite \
        -lfft2d_fftsg \
        -lfft2d_fftsg2d \
        -lflatbuffers \
        -lruy_ctx \
        -lruy_allocator \
        -lruy_frontend \
        -lruy_context_get_ctx \
        -lruy_context \
        -lruy_apply_multiplier \
        -lruy_prepacked_cache \
        -lruy_tune \
        -lruy_cpuinfo \
        -lruy_system_aligned_alloc \
        -lruy_prepare_packed_matrices \
        -lruy_trmul \
        -lruy_block_map \
        -lruy_denormal \
        -lruy_thread_pool \
        -lruy_blocking_counter \
        -lruy_wait \
        -lruy_kernel_avx \
        -lruy_kernel_avx2_fma \
        -lruy_kernel_avx512 \
        -lruy_pack_avx \
        -lruy_pack_avx2_fma \
        -lruy_pack_avx512 \
        -lruy_have_built_path_for_avx \
        -lruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma \
        -lruy_have_built_path_for_avx512 \
        -lfarmhash \
        -lXNNPACK \
        -lpthreadpool \
        -lcpuinfo \
        -lclog

CXX_FLAGS    := -Wall #-pedantic

LINK_FLAGS   :=

#Do not print the output of the commands
.SILENT:

#Phony targets do not represent actual files, so files with the following names are ignored
.PHONY: clean depend

#Link object files to form an executable file
$(EXE_FILE): $(OBJ_FILES)
        $(LINKER) $(LINK_FLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $(EXE_FILE) $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS)

#Compile cpp files to object files
%.o: %.cpp
        $(COMPILER) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -c $<

#Remove object files, executable, and possible linkinfo files
clean:
        -rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) $(EXE_FILE)

#Generate dependency file
depend:
        $(COMPILER) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -MM $(CXX_FILES) > make.dep

#Include dependency file
-include make.dep
```

Build and run MWE:

```
$ cd ~/my_tflite_project/my_dev_x64
$ make
$ ./app
Done
```

Hopefully that helps you or some other poor fellow to get TfLite C++ working.

Comment: It's not a year old, but a month old question. :-)

Comment: I even tried to link all `.a` into one `tf_dependencies.a` lib: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585671/failed-to-link-with-tensorflow-lite-c-api-static-library-undefined-reference-to. That didn't work too.

Comment: Here is a script on how to merge many libs into one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one/71585230#71585230.

Comment: Another thing: I must use TF Lite C API, not C++. And finally, I need to build for x8664, but also for Arm (armv7 32-bit and armv8 64-bit).

Comment: For Arm, replace `-lruy_kernel_avx*`, `-lruy_pack_avx*`, and `-lruy_have_built_path_for_avx*` with `-lruy_kernel_arm` and `-lruy_pack_arm`. Or always link to all the above libs if you don't mind redundancy on your platform.

Comment: I have also been thinking about merging the static libs into one static lib. But I deferred this to the end. At the moment I have it working on x64 and Arm64. At the end of the project I probably have more insight in how I want to package the software. I cannot distill from your answer whether you have TfLite working yet.

Comment: I only have experience with the C++ API. I would guess that with the C API you want to link to something like `-libtensorflowlite_c.a`. Do that, and then determine which other libraries you need.

Comment: For now I am using the shared lib - meaning, I still haven't been able to use the static lib. I have built the static lib, but then I have zillion of dependencies which I don't know how to link into final app - that's what [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585671/failed-to-link-with-tensorflow-lite-c-api-static-library-undefined-reference-to) is about.

Comment: Expanded my answer with detailed steps. Hopefully that should get you a working example. Good luck.

Comment: Could you run the app, and give us the output, so that we are sure app has everything it needs to link with to run?

Comment: Of course I could I run the compiled app. As for the output, there is no other output then "Done". :? It's a minimal-working example to test whether TfLite is working (since that is you're question about). To do inference you should extend the example.