# Failed to link with TensorFlow Lite C API static library? undefined reference to tflite::DefaultErrorReporter()

Tags: c, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've built the TensorFlow Lite static library, the C API version. Cloned [the sources](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) and called CMake:

```
cmake -S ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/c -DTFLITE_C_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
cmake --build . -j
```

This built the `libtensorflowlite_c.a`. I also linked all other `.a` sub-dependencies into a single `tensorflowdep.a` library (this includes `absl`, `clog` and all other transient dependencies listed here in the [TensorFlow CMake file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e41d9eb9edcc1ff2cf52736edde76e6f5d62f6ed/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt#L139)).

I tried to test the lib using a minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/c_api.h"

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello!");

    const char *version = TfLiteVersion();
    printf("Hello from TensorFlow Lite C API library version = %s\n", version);

    return 0;
}
```

`gcc -L"/home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow" -o "MAIN"  ./src/MAIN.o   -ltensorflowlite_c -ltensorflowdep`

But this fails:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteModelCreate':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x210): undefined reference to `tflite::DefaultErrorReporter()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0x22f): undefined reference to `tflite::FlatBufferModel::VerifyAndBuildFromBuffer(char const*, unsigned long, tflite::TfLiteVerifier*, tflite::ErrorReporter*)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteModelCreateFromFile':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `tflite::DefaultErrorReporter()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `tflite::FlatBufferModel::VerifyAndBuildFromFile(char const*, tflite::TfLiteVerifier*, tflite::ErrorReporter*)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0x384): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteModelDelete':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x433): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x452): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteInterpreterOptionsDelete':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x4a7): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteInterpreterCreate':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x560): undefined reference to `tflite::CreateOpResolver()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteInterpreterDelete':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x5fa): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteInterpreterResizeInputTensor':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x75a): undefined reference to `tflite::Interpreter::ResizeInputTensor(int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x7ee): undefined reference to `tflite::Interpreter::AllocateTensors()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `TfLiteInterpreterInvoke':
c_api.cc:(.text+0x824): undefined reference to `tflite::delegates::InterpreterUtils::InvokeWithCPUFallback(tflite::Interpreter*)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0x83e): undefined reference to `tflite::Interpreter::Invoke()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `tflite::internal::InterpreterCreateWithOpResolver(TfLiteModel const*, TfLiteInterpreterOptions const*, tflite::MutableOpResolver*)':
c_api.cc:(.text+0xaf5): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xb5b): undefined reference to `tflite::MutableOpResolver::AddAll(tflite::MutableOpResolver const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xbf1): undefined reference to `tflite::DefaultErrorReporter()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xc2f): undefined reference to `tflite::InterpreterBuilder::InterpreterBuilder(tflite::Model const*, tflite::OpResolver const&, tflite::ErrorReporter*)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xc53): undefined reference to `tflite::InterpreterBuilder::operator()(std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter, std::default_delete<tflite::Interpreter> >*)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xca7): undefined reference to `tflite::Interpreter::SetNumThreads(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xcd0): undefined reference to `tflite::NnApiDelegate()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xcdb): undefined reference to `tflite::Interpreter::ModifyGraphWithDelegate(TfLiteDelegate*)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xd88): undefined reference to `tflite::Interpreter::ModifyGraphWithDelegate(TfLiteDelegate*)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xe08): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xe67): undefined reference to `tflite::InterpreterBuilder::~InterpreterBuilder()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text+0xebe): undefined reference to `tflite::InterpreterBuilder::~InterpreterBuilder()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `(anonymous namespace)::CallbackOpResolver::~CallbackOpResolver()':
c_api.cc:(.text+0xf62): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `(anonymous namespace)::CallbackErrorReporter::~CallbackErrorReporter()':
c_api.cc:(.text+0xfba): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x8): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro+0x20): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `tflite::ErrorReporter::~ErrorReporter()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN6tflite13ErrorReporterD0Ev[_ZN6tflite13ErrorReporterD5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `tflite::OpResolver::~OpResolver()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN6tflite10OpResolverD0Ev[_ZN6tflite10OpResolverD5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `tflite::MutableOpResolver::MutableOpResolver()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN6tflite17MutableOpResolverC2Ev[_ZN6tflite17MutableOpResolverC5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for tflite::MutableOpResolver'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::default_delete<tflite::FlatBufferModel>::operator()(tflite::FlatBufferModel*) const':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNKSt14default_deleteIN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEclEPS1_[_ZNKSt14default_deleteIN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEclEPS1_]+0x22): undefined reference to `tflite::FlatBufferModel::~FlatBufferModel()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNKSt14default_deleteIN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEclEPS1_[_ZNKSt14default_deleteIN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEclEPS1_]+0x2a): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `void std::vector<TfLiteDelegate*, std::allocator<TfLiteDelegate*> >::_M_realloc_insert<TfLiteDelegate* const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<TfLiteDelegate**, std::vector<TfLiteDelegate*, std::allocator<TfLiteDelegate*> > >, TfLiteDelegate* const&)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIP14TfLiteDelegateSaIS1_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS1_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorIP14TfLiteDelegateSaIS1_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS1_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEDpOT_]+0x267): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIP14TfLiteDelegateSaIS1_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS1_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorIP14TfLiteDelegateSaIS1_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS1_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEDpOT_]+0x2d0): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIP14TfLiteDelegateSaIS1_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS1_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorIP14TfLiteDelegateSaIS1_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS1_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEDpOT_]+0x2dc): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `tflite::MutableOpResolver::~MutableOpResolver()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN6tflite17MutableOpResolverD2Ev[_ZN6tflite17MutableOpResolverD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for tflite::MutableOpResolver'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `tflite::MutableOpResolver::~MutableOpResolver()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN6tflite17MutableOpResolverD0Ev[_ZN6tflite17MutableOpResolverD5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::default_delete<tflite::Interpreter>::operator()(tflite::Interpreter*) const':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNKSt14default_deleteIN6tflite11InterpreterEEclEPS1_[_ZNKSt14default_deleteIN6tflite11InterpreterEEclEPS1_]+0x22): undefined reference to `tflite::Interpreter::~Interpreter()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNKSt14default_deleteIN6tflite11InterpreterEEclEPS1_[_ZNKSt14default_deleteIN6tflite11InterpreterEEclEPS1_]+0x2a): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::vector<TfLiteDelegate*, std::allocator<TfLiteDelegate*> >::_M_check_len(unsigned long, char const*) const':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorIP14TfLiteDelegateSaIS1_EE12_M_check_lenEmPKc[_ZNKSt6vectorIP14TfLiteDelegateSaIS1_EE12_M_check_lenEmPKc]+0x5f): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_S_check_init_len(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE17_S_check_init_lenEmRKS0_[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE17_S_check_init_lenEmRKS0_]+0x62): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::function<std::unique_ptr<TfLiteDelegate, void (*)(TfLiteDelegate*)> (int)> >::deallocate(std::function<std::unique_ptr<TfLiteDelegate, void (*)(TfLiteDelegate*)> (int)>*, unsigned long)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt8functionIFSt10unique_ptrI14TfLiteDelegatePFvPS3_EEiEEE10deallocateEPS9_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt8functionIFSt10unique_ptrI14TfLiteDelegatePFvPS3_EEiEEE10deallocateEPS9_m]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<tflite::FlatBufferModel*>(tflite::FlatBufferModel*)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC2IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_[_ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC5IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_]+0x26): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC2IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_[_ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC5IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_]+0x4d): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC2IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_[_ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC5IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_]+0x5e): undefined reference to `tflite::FlatBufferModel::~FlatBufferModel()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC2IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_[_ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC5IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_]+0x66): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC2IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_[_ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC5IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_]+0x6b): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC2IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_[_ZNSt14__shared_countILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EEC5IPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelEEET_]+0x77): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~_Sp_counted_base()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EED0Ev[_ZNSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EED5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<tflite::OpResolver const*>::deallocate(tflite::OpResolver const**, unsigned long)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIPKN6tflite10OpResolverEE10deallocateEPS4_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIPKN6tflite10OpResolverEE10deallocateEPS4_m]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<TfLiteDelegate*>::deallocate(TfLiteDelegate**, unsigned long)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIP14TfLiteDelegateE10deallocateEPS2_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIP14TfLiteDelegateE10deallocateEPS2_m]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x30): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x40): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<TfLiteDelegate*>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIP14TfLiteDelegateE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIP14TfLiteDelegateE8allocateEmPKv]+0x30): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIP14TfLiteDelegateE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIP14TfLiteDelegateE8allocateEmPKv]+0x40): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node_base*>::deallocate(std::__detail::_Hash_node_base**, unsigned long)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIPNSt8__detail15_Hash_node_baseEE10deallocateEPS3_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIPNSt8__detail15_Hash_node_baseEE10deallocateEPS3_m]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>::~pair()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt4pairINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEiED2Ev[_ZNSt4pairINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEiED5Ev]+0x18): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<std::pair<tflite::BuiltinOperator, int> const, TfLiteRegistration>, true> >::deallocate(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<std::pair<tflite::BuiltinOperator, int> const, TfLiteRegistration>, true>*, unsigned long)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt8__detail10_Hash_nodeISt4pairIKS3_IN6tflite15BuiltinOperatorEiE18TfLiteRegistrationELb1EEEE10deallocateEPSA_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt8__detail10_Hash_nodeISt4pairIKS3_IN6tflite15BuiltinOperatorEiE18TfLiteRegistrationELb1EEEE10deallocateEPSA_m]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> const, TfLiteRegistration>, true> >::deallocate(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> const, TfLiteRegistration>, true>*, unsigned long)':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt8__detail10_Hash_nodeISt4pairIKS3_INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEiE18TfLiteRegistrationELb1EEEE10deallocateEPSE_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt8__detail10_Hash_nodeISt4pairIKS3_INSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEiE18TfLiteRegistrationELb1EEEE10deallocateEPSE_m]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::_Sp_counted_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~_Sp_counted_ptr()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt15_Sp_counted_ptrIPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EED0Ev[_ZNSt15_Sp_counted_ptrIPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EED5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN6tflite10OpResolverE[_ZTVN6tflite10OpResolverE]+0x10): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN6tflite10OpResolverE[_ZTVN6tflite10OpResolverE]+0x18): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN6tflite13ErrorReporterE[_ZTVN6tflite13ErrorReporterE]+0x20): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE[_ZTVSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE]+0x20): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE[_ZTVSt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE]+0x30): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTISt15_Sp_counted_ptrIPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE[_ZTISt15_Sp_counted_ptrIPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6tflite10OpResolverE[_ZTIN6tflite10OpResolverE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6tflite13ErrorReporterE[_ZTIN6tflite13ErrorReporterE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTISt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE[_ZTISt16_Sp_counted_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o): in function `std::_Sp_counted_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose()':
c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt15_Sp_counted_ptrIPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE10_M_disposeEv[_ZNSt15_Sp_counted_ptrIPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE10_M_disposeEv]+0x22): undefined reference to `tflite::FlatBufferModel::~FlatBufferModel()'
/usr/bin/ld: c_api.cc:(.text._ZNSt15_Sp_counted_ptrIPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE10_M_disposeEv[_ZNSt15_Sp_counted_ptrIPN6tflite15FlatBufferModelELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE10_M_disposeEv]+0x2a): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTISt11_Mutex_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE[_ZTISt11_Mutex_baseILN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/joedoe/out/subprojects/tensorflow/libtensorflowlite_c.a(c_api.cc.o):(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:45: TF] Error 1
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try using `g++`

Comment: Using `g++` to compile the `MAIN.c` and to link didn't help, error output seems to be the same. `g++ -L"/home/joedoe/subprojects/tensorflow" -o "MAIN"  ./src/MAIN.o   -ltensorflowlite_c -ltensorflowdep`