# Tensorflow 2.8 cmake static built static library showing undefined reference for ruy, flatbuffers

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, static-linking

I built tensorflow-lite.a with cmake using instruction from [tensorflow cmake build](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake).

But when trying to use this library in cpp application I'm getting undefined reference errors (mostly from ruy).

1. My guess is tensorflow-lite.a does not contain all the necessery libraries like ruy, am I correct??
2. Do I need to build RUY separately ?? to use tensorflow-lite??
3. Is only way possible to use this static library is by adding sub_directory in your cmake ??

Attaching a log of error:

```
Init(TfLiteContext*, char const*, unsigned long)':
mfcc.cc:(.text+0x15c0): undefined reference to `flatbuffers::ClassicLocale::instance_'
mfcc.cc:(.text+0x1634): undefined reference to `flatbuffers::ClassicLocale::instance_'
mfcc.cc:(.text+0x16aa): undefined reference to `flatbuffers::ClassicLocale::instance_'
mfcc.cc:(.text+0x1b7b): undefined reference to `flatbuffers::ClassicLocale::instance_'
.
.
.
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x138e): undefined reference to `ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x13a5): undefined reference to `ruy::ThreadPool::ExecuteImpl(int, int, ruy::Task*)'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x1460): undefined reference to `ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x1479): undefined reference to `ruy::ThreadPool::ExecuteImpl(int, int, ruy::Task*)'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x1534): undefined reference to `ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x154d): undefined reference to `ruy::ThreadPool::ExecuteImpl(int, int, ruy::Task*)'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x1763): undefined reference to `ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x190b): undefined reference to `ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x1ab2): undefined reference to `ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x1c69): undefined reference to `ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()'
mirror_pad.cc:(.text+0x1e3a): undefined reference to `ruy::Context::mutable_thread_pool()'
/path/libtensorflow-lite.a(numeric_verify.cc.o): In function `tflite::ops::custom::numeric_verify::Init(TfLiteContext*, char const*, unsigned long)':
numeric_verify.cc:(.text+0xcd1): undefined reference to `flatbuffers::ClassicLocale::instance_'
numeric_verify.cc:(.text+0x10e7): undefined reference to `flatbuffers::ClassicLocale::instance_'
```

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72100557/7268445

Answer (score 1):

1. Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported downloads
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
2. Python 3.7+ 64-bit release for Windows
   https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
3. Those reading are in the same directory as in the CMakeList at "F:/temp/tflite/tensorflow_src/tflite_build/ruy/ruy/CMakeLists.txt"
4. Compile using the Lastest C++