# CMake - combine multiple libraries into one

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have executables A, B, C, and I have external libraries X, Y, Z

```
SET(EXTERNAL_LIB X Y Z)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(A, ${EXTERNAL_LIB})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(B, ${EXTERNAL_LIB})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(C, ${EXTERNAL_LIB})
```

However, if I visualize this (using `cmake --graphviz` option, I get a complex bipartite graph with edges from each of the executables A, B, and C to each of the libraries X, Y, and Z.

I was wondering if there's a way to combine all the libraries into one.

Comment: Actually I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of this depends a bit on your platform, compiler and the type of libraries:

1. In case, you can build X, Y, Z yourself: Create a new project `XYZ`, built from the aggregated source files of X, Y and Z. But I guess if this was possible, you would not have asked on SO.
2. If you can not rebuild the libs and they were built as a shared libraryy (dll/so), you are out of luck. You could try to write a wrapper library, which hides all the internals of X, Y and Z and which will be used by applications A, B and C.
3. If they were build as static libs, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665752/combining-static-libraries). Because a static lib is not much more than an archive of object files, you may be able to extract the object code from each lib and recombine them with `ar`.

But why would you? Suppose you get a fourth application D, which only depends on X. Then you would need the separate library Y anyway (unless you prefer to unnecessarily link with all libs).