# Combine static libraries on Apple

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, static-libraries

I tried the approach in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one), but it seems the linux version of `ar` is not the same as the mac version since I failed to combine the object files again.

What I basically want to do is is merge another static library into my Xcode static library build product via a run-script build phase.

Unfortunately I can't compile the other library directly into my project because it has it's own build system (therefore I use the compiled libs).

I think it should be possible to merge the other library via `ar` into the Xcode generated library without decompiling the build product. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

you can use `libtool` to do it

```
libtool -static -o new.a old1.a old2.a
```

Comment: This is actually a better solution than `ar`. Thanks!

Comment: any command line (bash), you should have libtool in PATH provided you have the developpers' extension. Alternatively, as a post build step in xcode.

Comment: You need to download and install `libtool`. This is in the Xcode's command line tool.

Comment: @MohamMad I've added this call as a build phase script. More details at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21225126/239408

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Added it as a run-script build step in XCode and worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Does this command rename object files with overlapping names so that duplicate files can both be accessed in the resulting archive library?  On MacOS the lib tool command complains about duplicate names.

Answer (score 8):

If you're dealing with multi-architecture static libraries, a bit of extra manipulation is required to thin each library, combine the thinned versions, and then fatten the result. Here's a handy script which you can edit to your satisfaction which does all that in one. The example takes three iOS libraries `path/to/source/libs/libone.a`, `path/to/source/libs/libtwo.a`, and `path/to/source/libs/libthree.a` and merges them into a single library `libcombined.a`.

```
#! /bin/bash

INPATH="path/to/source/libs"

LIBPREFIX="lib"
LIBS="one two three"
LIBEXT=".a"

OUT="combined"

ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64"

for arch in $ARCHS
do
  for lib in $LIBS
  do
    lipo -extract $arch $INPATH/$LIBPREFIX$lib$LIBEXT -o $LIBPREFIX$lib-$arch$LIBEXT
  done
  INLIBS=`eval echo $LIBPREFIX\{${LIBS// /,}\}-$arch$LIBEXT`
  libtool -static -o $LIBPREFIX$OUT-$arch$LIBEXT $INLIBS
  rm $INLIBS
done

OUTLIBS=`eval echo $LIBPREFIX$OUT-\{${ARCHS// /,}\}$LIBEXT`
lipo -create $OUTLIBS -o $LIBPREFIX$OUT$LIBEXT
rm $OUTLIBS
```

Comment: This script did not seem to deal with overlapping names.  The last limo command warned about duplicate names and the TOC did not show any for of disambiguation, so I think it would not work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be necessary any more, `libtool -static` can directly combine fat static libraries

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to link one to the other. So... just use `ld` to merge the images.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ar -r` to create an archive on MacOS:

```
ar -x libabc.a
ar -x libxyz.a
ar -r libaz.a  *.o
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all.  You're going to overwrite files that have the same .o names.