# Linking 2 static libs into 1 for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created two separate static libraries in Xcode for usage on iOS, A and B. A uses methods that are defined in B.

When creating a new Xcode project where both A and B are needed, I can include them separately. However, for simplicity of integration I prefer to create a Universal Framework that contains both A and B.

Is it possible in Xcode to merge 2 static libraries into 1, without merging the code of the 2 libraries in 1 project. In other words. Can I somehow link the compiled static library B into static library A when I am compiling/Linking static library A?

If this is possible, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170450/combine-static-libraries

Comment: Also related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442593/including-third-party-librariesexample-afnetworking-in-static-library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just run some quick tests and it seems to be happening automatically. This is what I did:

- I used **DerivedData** folder as a default build location for all 3 projects (this is default in XCode 4.2 which I use)
- I changed **Public Headers Folder Path** to **include/ProjectX** where X is the name of the static library. I did this step only for static libraries A and B, not for the project that will actually link them. This step is to be able to import the headers like `<LibX/Header.h>`.
- I made library B direct dependency of the library A and linked A against B
- I made library A direct dependency of the main project and linked main project against A

After this basic setup, I imported classes from B to A with something similar to `<LibB/Header.h>` and wrote some code that actually made use of B. Then, I imported A and B to the main project with `<LibA/Header.h>` and `<LibB/Header.h>` and wrote code that made use of A and B. Finally, I went to the **DerivedData** folder with the terminal and navigated to the location where A is built. I checked if LibA.a contains objects from LibB with:

```
nm LibA.a
```

And yes, it contains objects from LibB. So, to sum up, with this simple dependency setup you should be able to get what you asked for.

**EDIT**
To make B direct dependency of A and link A against B do this:

Having A open in the XCode, go to Finder and drag&drop B project file into A. Then, choose the root element in A, go to Build Phases, expand Target Dependencies, press '+' button, choose B and confirm. then expand Link Binary With Libraries, press '+' button, choose B.a (or whatever the product name is) and confirm.

**Important**
There is a bug in XCode that prevents you from properly dropping B project file into A workspace. Instead, you are left with B project file in A workspace, but you cannot expand B and do anything with it. To work around this problem, remove the faulty B project file reference from A, close A, close B if you have it open. Then reopen A and use Finder to navigate to B project file, then drag&drop B inside A workspace. If didn't work, repeat.

**EDIT2**
I case you don't have access to the sources of B (and possibly A), making this work is just a matter of copying the required headers in the proper place. Then in you main project, you don't make the A direct dependency, instead you link against static libA.a that you have. If A uses B, then the symbols from B are already in the libA.a. You can check this with **nm** tool like I do above. So we are down to exposing those symbols to the main application with B headers. There are a couple of ways to do it, I remember that I simply copied the headers to the *Copy Headers* destination path of the library that is in the middle of the dependency chain. After that, by linking against A and adding A headers to **User Header Search Paths** I was able to access B directly. What is the best way to do it for you depends on if you have access to the sources of A. If you have, there are two options to consider:

- Add B headers to A (they will be automatically copied to the A headers destination). But I guess you don't want this solution.
- Add custom run script build phase to A target, which will grab the B headers and copy them to A headers destination.

In both cases, you end up with LibA.a which holds compiled sources of A and B, and the headers folder which holds headers from A and B. You can then link your main project agains LibA.a and add the headers folder path to the **User Headers Search Path** in you main project, and you should be good to go.

**Important**

If, in your libraries, you have files that hold only category code in them, make sure to link this library with **-force_load**, or your category symbols will not be packed properly.

Comment: Lawicko, thanks for your response. A question I am left with is how you create the dependency when you write "I made library B direct dependency of the library A and linked A against B" ?

Comment: Lawicko, it works after I closed all projects :-) I'm however, not entirely satisfied with the solution, because when I drag and drop the B project file into the A project, the source code for B is exposed to project A (I can expand project B on the left and see all the project code there. I am not sure if that can be solved somehow (I'd rather just drag and drop static lib B into the project and force Xcode to merge B into static lib A when I compile A. I'll accept the answer though as I've learned something new about xcode thanks to you :-)

Comment: Yeah, this drag&drop part is a pain on the back side. I'm glad you made it!

Comment: The fact that you can see lib B when browsing A does not mean that the files from B are now part of A. They are not. This direct dependency trick only tells XCode to recompile B before compiling A. However, I know what you are referring to. What If you don't have access to the sources of B? Then you just want to link to the static libB.a and add headers. I managed to do it in the past with the Reachability library, give me some time and I'll let you know how to do this.

Comment: See my edited answer for the case when you don't have access to the library sources.

Answer (score 3):

I've done it with libtool, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8170851/239408).

To do so, in Xcode 5.0.2, I've added a script to A (`Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add Run Script Build Phase`) that

- figures out the architecture for which A is being built:

  ```
  LIPO_ARCH=$(lipo -info ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME} | awk 'END{ print $NF }')
  ```
- creates a thin version of B, with only the architecture being built

  ```
  lipo -thin ${LIPO_ARCH} ${FULLPATH_OF_B} -output ${FULLPATH_OF_THIN_B}
  ```
- joins A and B into a new A

  ```
  mv ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${FULLPATH_OF_THIN_A}
  libtool -static -o ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${FULLPATH_OF_THIN_A} ${FULLPATH_OF_THIN_B}
  ```
- removes the temp files

  ```
  rm ${FULLPATH_OF_THIN_A}
  rm ${FULLPATH_OF_THIN_B}
  ```