# How to merge static libraries for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Just to clarify, **I am not talking about merging different architectures static libraries into one here**.

I have a static library that depends on several other static libraries. The problem is that I don't want our customer to bother to include all those `.a` files, but instead **only one** containing all the objects and code they need.

So how could I merge several static libraries into one? Or is it possible to include those static libraries when I build the static library through XCode?

Comment: You can use `libtool`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531014/linking-2-static-libs-into-1-for-ios/21225126#21225126 for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `libtool` command line utility for this. Here is the syntax:

Let’s say the directory `libs` has all the static libs and you want to create `libfatstatic.a` out of it.

```
libtool -static -o libfatstatic.a libs/*.a
```

Note: If you don’t have libtool. You can install the same using brew : `brew install libtool`

Comment: When merging those files, I received a bunch of warning saying that for xxx architecture, there is no symbol in xxx.a. And after import the merged static library, I didn't have errors in compile-time but have run-time error.. What may be the reason of this?

Comment: So you do not get any errors if you include those files without merging?