# Is there a better way to combine static libraries without carrying a bunch of unnecessary code?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, libtool

As I saw here ([Combine static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170450/combine-static-libraries/8170851#8170851)) I may combine more than one static library using libtool

```
libtool -static -o new.a old1.a old2.a
```

As far as I know, this will concatenate every single function from the old libraries to the new one. But what I really want are the functions from the new.a library, the others are there for dependency purpose. Is there a way to combine only the part required by the new.a from the other libraries without carrying a bunch of unnecessary code?

Comment: Along with dropping the unnecessary code it would be nice to keep the symbols from the old libraries from being exported too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract from the old libraries those object files you wish to incorporate in the new.  But there really isn't much point in worrying about it; the linker will only link those object files that are necessary, unlike a shared library where all the symbols defined in the shared library are available to the executable (not that it uses them all, usually).

The old-fashioned way to do the job would be:

```
mkdir new
cd new
ar x ../old1.a
ar x ../old2.a
ar rv ../new.a *.o
cd ..
rm -fr new
```

After the two `x` operations, you can weed and whittle the object files to keep what you want for use in `new.a`.