# How to make a static lib based on other static libs using GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, static-libraries, ld

I want to make a static library called `libXYZ.a` using some existing static libraries: `libX.a`, `libY.a`, `libZ.a` and some object files. The command line I used to build the static library `libXYZ.a` is:

```
ld -o libXYZ.a one.o two.o -L./ -L/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2 -lX -lY -lZ -lstdc++
```

I'm using Cygwin GCC (g++) to compile `one.cpp` and `two.cpp` to get `one.o` and `two.o` before the `ld` command like the following:

```
g++ -o one.o one.cpp -c
g++ -o one.o two.cpp -c
```

`libX.a`, `libY`.a, `libZ.a` are all located in the current directory (that's why `-L./`). And I added the C++ standard library linker flag `-lstdc++` in the `ld` line. But I got the following error when I make it:

```
one.o: one.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
ld: one.o: bad reloc address 0xd in section `.text$_ZN10ConfigC1Ev[__ZN10ConfigC1Ev]'
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'libXYZ.a' failed
```

So my question is: Is the `ld` command the right command to build the static lib from other static libs and .o files? What caused the error? I searched the forum and found that it is possible caused by some incompatible compiler. But I built all my source code using the same GCC compiler.

UPDATE:

I tried again using the following command:

```
ld -o libXYZ.a one.o two.o -L./ -lX -lY -lZ
```

But I'm still getting the following errors:

```
one.o:one.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
one.o:one.cpp:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
...
./libX.a(wrapper.o):wrapper.cpp:(.text+0x7ba): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
./libX.a(wrapper.o):wrapper.cpp:(.text+0x7ba): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
...
```

And I omitted numerous similar errors like the above `_Unwind_Resume` errors. Any ideas on what caused those errors?

Comment: This should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8170851/2298578

Comment: Unfortunately my cygwin gcc doesn't support libtool, only `ld` is supported.

Answer (score -1):

> So my question is: Is the ld command the right command to build the static lib from other static libs and .o files?

No. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821949/50617) for how this can be done.

Comment: If I use `ar` instead of `ld` command to link three static libs as the link you gave, then I need to do three `ar -x` commands and then one more `ar -c` command to link all extracted `*.o` object files. Is there a one-pass solution using either `ar` or `ld` to link `libX.a`, `libY.a`, `libZ.a` with two object files in current directory: `one.o`, `two.o` to form the new static lib `libXYZ.a`? IMHO using four `ar` commands to extract and compress libs is too cumbersome.

Comment: @tonga "using four ar commands to extract and compress libs is too cumbersome" -- don't do it by hand, write `Makefile` instead. A shell script wraping the `ar` invocations is also quite trivial to write.