# How to use libtool to create a static library from a bunch of static libraries

Tags: c, libtool

I have around 80 static libraries. I would like to create one static library from that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170450/combine-static-libraries/8170851#8170851) didn't work for me since I get the following error:

```
libtool: unrecognized option `-static'
```

I am also confused as to which mode it needs to be done in. Is it "link" or "install"
Since there 20 odd libraries, can I also use "*" to specify all?

I didn't find any information in document expect [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Static-libraries.html) which doesn't really answer my question.

FYI..These are the modes:

```
MODE must be one of the following:

      clean           remove files from the build directory
      compile         compile a source file into a libtool object
      execute         automatically set library path, then run a program
      finish          complete the installation of libtool libraries
      install         install libraries or executables
      link            create a library or an executable
      uninstall       remove libraries from an installed directory
```

Comment: To create a static library using `libtool`, all those 80 static libraries must have been compiled with `libtool --mode=compile` and not plain `gcc`. Also, could you share your output for `which libtool` and `ls -l <the path output in the which libtool command>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm probably naively ignoring some consequence, but couldn't you just treat the files directly as archives?

```
for i in *.a; ar x $i; done
ar r libfoo.a *.o
ranlib libfoo.a
```

Of course, you'll need some kind of renaming scheme if any of the `.o` files are the same. Probably something like `libname_objectname.o`.

Comment: This won't work if there are duplicate *.o files in different *.a library. They will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

The first linked answer is about the Mac OS `libtool`, not GNU libtool.

The second link actually might work (shown here wrapped with Makefile variables), if you don't mind writing an install hook:

```
$(LIBTOOL) $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=install $(AR) cru "$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libsponge.a" libfoo.a libbar.a ...
```

The libtool "link" mode seems very fussy with respect to static libs.  I was able to do it but it gave me warnings -- one for each static library, which would be a huge cascade for you.

It might be easier to bypass `libtool` in this case, though.  This will work with GNU ar:

```
lib_LIBRARIES=libsponge.a
libsponge.a : libfoo.a libbar.a ...
        echo "CREATE $@" > libsponge-script
        list='$^'; for p in $$list; do \
            echo "ADDLIB $$p" >> libsponge-script; \
        done
        echo "SAVE" >> libsponge-script
        $(AR) -M < libsponge-script
        $(RANLIB) $@
```

If this must be portable, something like this will work:

```
lib_LIBRARIES=libsponge.a
libsponge.a : libfoo.a libbar.a ...
        $(AR) cru $@
        $(MKDIR_P) tmpar
        list='$^'; for p in $$list; do \
            (cd tmpar; $(AR) x "../$$p"; $(AR) q "../$@" *.o; rm *.o;) \
        done
        rm -rf tmpar
        $(RANLIB) $@
```

Comment: Thanks but The last solution does not work. 
I get "could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one" even though I ran ranlib. ar t linspnge.a gives a list of libraries and not object files which I think is a problem

Comment: As far as I know, you have to extract the .o files first, and then create the new archive from those. The docs do not suggest that it will automatically extract objects from input archives. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Nikhil, so you are saying that one of your input `.a` files has no index?

Comment: No. The output library doesn't have an index. The output library when extracted contains .a's instead of .o's

Comment: Sorry, @Nikhil, I forgot that `ar` doesn't look in the archive in this case.  I did remember that GNU ar does have kind of an obscure way of doing what you want.  Maybe that will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

libtool looks at the parameters of gcc, so you should have something like below

```
$ cat Makefile
all: libone libtwo
        rm *.o
        @libtool --mode=link gcc -all-static -o libcombo.a libone.a libtwo.a

libone: one.c
        @libtool --mode=compile gcc -c one.c -o one.lo
        @libtool --mode=link gcc -static -o libone.a one.lo

libtwo: two.c
        @libtool --mode=compile gcc -c two.c -o two.lo
        @libtool --mode=link gcc -static -o libtwo.a two.lo

clean:
        rm -rf .libs *.lo *.o *.a
```