# Possible to link multiple static libs into one with same arch?

Tags: c++, c, macos, dart, lipo

I have many projects that link against a new VM (dart), which currently requires each project to link against 6 static libraries. I would like to simplify process by creating one static library that needs to then be linked into each project.  I was hoping that I could do this with `lipo`, but the `-create` command seems to only accept static libs of different architectures:

```
lipo -create libdart_builtin.a libdart_lib_withcore.a libdart_vm.a libdart_withcore.a libdouble_conversion.a libjscre.a -output libdart_runtime.a
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: libdart_builtin.a and libdart_lib_withcore.a have the same architectures (x86_64) and can't be in the same fat output file
```

This is on Mac OS X. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible? I suppose I could build the static libs into one other project, but I'd prefer to package all of the required binaries for this VM into one for easier distribution purposes.

Comment: I think this is a dupe, but I'm nervous about using the hammer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8170450/10077

Comment: @FredLarson: why nervous? That dupe looks exactly right.

Comment: Indeed - `libtool -static` worked great for this purpose, thanks for pointing me to the answer.