# How to access a third party framework from My.Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

Steps to understand my problem:

1) I created a framework (My.framework)

2) Added My.framework as a subproject to MyApp.xcodeproj.

3) Then I ran cocoapod for adding `AFNetworking` on MyApp.xcodeproj.

4) Now, I open MyApp.xcworkspace.

5) While trying to access `AFNetworking` from classes in My.framework. It is not accessible.

> P.S. I am not talking about "umbrella framework". (Umbrella framework
>   is where we add a framework as a framework of sub project.)(Correct me
>   here if I am wrong)

I just want to access `AFNetworking` while it is still out of the My.framework

Comment: You add AFNetworking to your app, not to your framework. I think that's the problem.

Comment: But, I need access to AFN in both the app and FW.

Comment: If I add AFN to FW, then the FW will become a `workspace` . and WS cannot be added as a subproject to an app.

Answer (score 2):

Add a podspec for your framework and include necessary dependencies such as AFNetworking.

```
 pod spec create
```

Then include your podspec in app's Podfile.

Ps: You don't have to publish your podspec, you can use it locally.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for being here. I am getting "[!] Unknown command: `init`" while hitting this command.

Comment: Is it ... `pod spec create My` ?

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat yeah sorry, it's `create`. This should create a boilerplate pod spec file for you. Just if you work with Cocoapods then you better maintain everything through them too. Podspecs are great to describe complex dependencies and simplify things on the outside when you have to link your framework. Also, CocoaPods should take care of embedding frameworks for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , this is working.

Adjust Public Header files in Target-> Build Phase-> Copy Headers. We can set the header file visibility here.

[image]

Refer more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27638841/3901620

Answer (score 0):

**Another Way**

whenever you don't use pod then use this.

**IN Objective C**

1) Import or simply Copy (drag and drop) AFNetworking or any other class which you use in your project.

[image]

2) Import it where you use.

[image]

Done now you can access it.

**In Swift**

You just import or copy third party class or framework in your project you don't need to import it where you use.